# Form elements not appearing in $scope

Tags: angularjs

Here's the start of my form...

```
<div ng-form name="CustomerForm" ng-controller="Customer">
```

Here's my controller...

```
app.controller('Customer', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

   alert($scope.CustomerForm);
}]);
```

`$scope.CustomerForm` is undefined. Shouldn't the form be added to scope?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At the time of your alert statement, CustomerForm isn't within `$scope` yet.

Controllers are meant to:

1. Create an initial state of a scope object.
2. Add behavior to that scope object.

Read more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) about controllers.

---

### The "Solution?"

See here: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/389/)

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('Customer', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    
    $scope.getFormName = function(){
        console.log($scope.CustomerForm.$name);
    }
}]);
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-form name="CustomerForm" ng-controller="Customer">
    <button ng-click="getFormName()">CLICK</button>
</div>
```