# Angular JS Binding to Form Within a Controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a form initialized like this --

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8" ng-controller="myController">
                <form name="userForm" class="form-horizontal"  role="form" novalidate>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputb" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 control-label">Beam Width</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-5">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputb" placeholder="Input width in mm" ng-model="user.inputb" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
</div>
```

Ideally then i should be able to access the form from within the controller like this ---

```
angular.module("myApp",[])
    .controller("myController",function($http,$scope){
        //user is bound to the form inputs
        var i = $scope.userForm.inputb.$pristine;
        console.log(i); //expected to be true or false
        console.log($scope.userForm);
            console.log(userForm);
```

But the first console output gives out message - Cannot access property M of undefined
And second console output gives out obvious message "undefined"
Interesting the third console output does give out the userForm object! 
What is happening here, Why am i not able to access the form elements by name within the controller as expected? Why removing $scope prints the object? This doesnt solve the problem as then just userForm.M.$pristine is again "undefined".

P.S. I am debugging something for which i require this in controller. Specifically this wasnt working in the view too, where i wanted to do a ng-show of an error message if inputb is not entered.

Comment: Please,create a fiddle.

Comment: It is the same problem explained in this SO question: [Form elements not appearing in $scope][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18657394/645428

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that form is just not yet initialized. As you can see in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TQbLv2TzRHmaXH7yZwjH?p=preview), everything works fine in timeout. But as far as I know, $scope.userForm is not intended to be used in this way (on controller init). It may be used:

1. In template to declarativly describe classes, or disabling submit
   button, etc. Using it in expressions will never generate exceptions.
2. On submit. It will be initialized for that moment for sure